# Custom attribute on billing address not added

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, billing-address

I would like to add a custom attribute on billing address module.

Below are my Code:

app/etc/modules/Ucs_BillAddress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ucs_BillAddress>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ucs_BillAddress>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Below is the app/code/local/Ucs/BillAddress/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ucs_BillAddress>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ucs_BillAddress>
    </modules>
    <resource>
        <address_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ucs_BillAddress</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class> <!-- This is the important thing-->
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </address_setup>
    </resource>
</config>
```

Below is my sql code: app\code\local\Ucs\BillAddress\sql\ucs_setup\mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'site_id', array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Site ID',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 1,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'visible_on_front' => 0
    ));
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'site_id')
        ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer_address'))
        ->save();
    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

But after clearing cache, in System->Configuration->Advanced I can see my module added but the customer field site_id not added. I dont know whats my mistake on above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @DavidManners said `sql/ucs_setup` should be changed as `sql/address_setup`. In addition with two more mistakes are

1. It should be `<resources>` not `<resource>`
2. `<resources>` tag should be inside `<global>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your code the folder for the set-up script is wrong. I think it should be `address_setup` instead of `ucs_setup`. This is the node defined in the config.xml you have posted.

Comment: I will try that one.. Now can I use install script or update script since al ready my module config file  run

Comment: check the table `core_resource` if your module is there then remove it or reset the config value. if it is not there then you have no issue

Comment: I can see only in advanced tab in admin not in core_resource but still the attribute not added. I have no error log also. Error log enabled.

Comment: I am sorry, I did a blender mistake.. 1. it should be `<resources>` not `<resource>` 2. It should be inside `<global>` tag. Thanks @DavidManners

Comment: @version.beta feel free to add your answer if it is now sorted

Comment: I poted the answer, what you said also correct sql files folder name should be `address_setup` not `ucs_setup`. +1 thanks.